# why copy-from-recipe doesn't add any file to my base project?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, recipe, symfony-flex

I run a local flex server in my local pc (windows) from : https://github.com/moay/server-for-symfony-flex

and I made a recipe with config/routes/api-form-bundle.yaml
and my manifest :

```
{
  "bundles": {
    "XXX\\ApiFormBundle\\XXXApiFormBundle": ["all"]
  },
  "copy-from-recipe": {
    "config/": "%CONFIG_DIR%/"
  },
  "composer-scripts": {
    "make:migration": "symfony-cmd"
  },
  "aliases": ["xxx-apiform", "xxxapiform"]
}
```

I expect api-form.yaml file added to config/routes directory in my base project after composer install but nothing added. (alias and scripts work without problem)

what is the problem? am I write anything wrong?

Comment: How did you run that recipe? What happens instead? Have you checked whether the recipe was run once before you've added that config line?

Comment: when I run composer require xxx-apiform after installation the recipe scripts run but no config file generated.